# Shortening Eclipse git workflow

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I use a rebase workflow with Egit in Eclipse. I work on a local branch, call it "working" for the purposes of this question. When I'm ready to integrate my changes, I have to:

1. Switch to `master`
2. Pull (fast-forward)
3. Switch to `working`
4. Rebase `master`, resolving any conflicts
5. Switch to `master`
6. Merge `working`
7. Push.

As you can see, there is a lot of branch switching going on. It's not a big time drain, since switching branches is pretty fast. However the time adds up and it's additional steps to teach new people to do. What I'd really like to do is, while on `working`:

1. Pull (resulting in `master` being updated)
2. Rebase `master`
3. Switch to `master`
4. Merge `working`
5. Push

In this workflow, I also wouldn't have to completely unnecessarily switch branches just to pull in changes and continue working. Just pull, rebase, continue.

How do you configure git to always update `master` on a pull, even if you're on another branch? I'd prefer an answer that uses Egit, but command line solutions are acceptable too - they may be able to be performed with Egit.

Comment: Not really sure, if this helps: Have you ever looked at the "rebase" pull strategy when creating a new branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rather:

- `fetch` (no need to change your current branch working)
- `rebase origin/master working`
- switch to `master` and merge `working` (fast-forward)

The last step would update master with both `origin/master` and `working`.

Comment: I'll try this and see how it works out. The only potential issue I see is that if I want a clean branch I'll have to switch to master and pull before branching...although, I could just branch origin/master, couldn't I. I keep forgetting that branches are essentially tags on the commit tree.